# How do I change the File Permission? Im trying to install pry

Tags: ruby, terminal

While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0 directory.

Comment: have you tried using sudo?

Comment: Please, do not suggest escalating to superuser privileges until you have a complete and comprehensive understanding of the problem. In 99% of cases, if a user does not have write permissions, there is a *reason* for it. That reason might very well be that the system is configured wrong and the user should actually have access, but then just blindly throwing `sudo` at it is *still* not the correct solution: fixing the wrong configuration is the correct solution.

Comment: how are you trying to install pry, add steps to the question description.